# How to copy file one at a time

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created a .bat file with below commands:

```
@echo off
net use B: "\\C:\Folder2"
:loop
FOR %%f IN (D:\Folder1\*.jpeg) DO (
    move %%f B:\
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak
)
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Now I want this bat file to execute every 2 seconds and for that I have the below code:

```
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
    goto :loop
```

And then I want to read all the jpeg file created in Folder1 one by one at an interval of one second.

```
FOR %%f IN (D:\Folder1\*.jpeg) DO (
        move %%f B:\
        timeout /t 1 /nobreak
    )
```

But For loop is not moving the files one at a time.

Also, when the For loop is engaged, the next instance of main loop starts.

What I want is that until For loop doesn't complete its job, don't start the main loop.

Also, I want to first move those files first with oldest date time value.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't seem to understand the for loop right. The commands in parentheses following the do are executed for every element the `in (..)` specifies. Your label :loop and goto :loop creates an additional infinite loop but once the files are moved there is nothing left to move.

Comment: Thanks for the reply LotPings. But its not when there is no data in the folder but it the time when I do have data in the folder, the for loop  is executing but two seconds later , another instance of :loop start which again invokes the for loop.

Comment: This is what your loop is doing. Move every jpeg one by one with a one second gap between each move operation. When all jpegs have been moved, wait for two seconds and start again. At this point unless more jpegs have been moved into that directory, it will just keep waiting for two seconds before trying again. The script will never end until it's forcibly terminated. Is that not what you intended it to do?

Comment: Batch files are not multithreaded.  What you describe cannot possibly happen.  Batch files execute code line by line.  It does not move onto the next command until the previous command is finished.

Comment: But why is it starting new instance, I have no clue. Also, how can I move the files based on dates ascending order

Comment: hm. Only imaginable reason for the described behaviour: your batchfile is named `move.bat`...

Comment: @Roy, please try to better explain the process you want the script to perform. Don't tell us anything about the posted script just lay out the steps one by one in the order you expect it to happen. Please also ensure that your batch file is not `move.bat` or `move.cmd`, _or any other internal or external executable name within the working directory or `%PATH%`_. Files with extensions listed in `%PATHEXT%` will run, _in the priority order shown_, without their extension so naming can be critical.

Comment: Thanks for the response Compo. What I am trying to achieve with the Batch file is to move the jpeg files which are getting generated each seconds one at a time and also I want to move based date and time in ascending order and I want to keep checking for files in the folder every 2 seconds. And this is a standalone batch job

Comment: I don't understand! If you're moving the files one by one every second, what difference does the sort order make, _especially as they're all going to the same location_. Also we would appreciate feedback on the name of the batch file, so that we can verify if the new instance issue has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Compo. Accidently I configured two Windows scheduler and because of that I was having multiple instances at once. But I am not able to figure out how I can move the oldest date time file first

Comment: So the files that I get is somewhere around 20 files per second in Folder1 and the files names have serial number in it. Now there is a custom software who is listening to Folder 2 and processing and printing it onto printers. Now I want to make sure that the files that have been created first are read first as well that's why I want to read the oldest date time file first

Comment: If you want to get the oldest file first, then you need to capture the output of the `DIR` command with a `FOR /F` command.  `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /OD *.jpg') DO.......`

Comment: @Roy, I've spent a lot of time and effort trying to coerce sufficient information from you in order to give you the best chance of quality answers and to help you to learn; but you've deleted three or four of them in the space of a couple of days. Can you please tell me how that motivates anybody to provide comments or help to you in this or any other question? It seems to me as if the only way moving the files in sorted order would matter is if you moved them only if the listener was capable of receiving ordered files at a rate of 1200 per minute.

Comment: @Roy what is the name of your batch file?

Comment: Hi Gerhard. Thanks for the response. The name of the file is CopyPrintFiles.bat